# Haskell, two elements from one list followed by one element other list? (pattern matching)

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

i have a function that will take two elements from one list and one element from the second list, but there is a problem, if the given list has only one element:

example:

```
*Main> g2 [1] [5..10]
[1]
```

I want to have a output like this:

```
*Main> g2 [1] [5..10]
[1,5]
```

It works for list with more than 1 element:

```
*Main> g2 [1..5] [8..10]
[1,2,8,3,4,9,5]
*Main> g2 [1,2,3,4] [6,7,8,9]
[1,2,6,3,4,7]
```

My Code:

```
g2 (x1:x2:xs) (y:ys) = x1:x2:y:(g2 xs ys)
g2 (x1:[]) y = x1:[]
g2 [] ys = []
```

I think i forgot a pattern.

Comment: Your second clause directly adresses that case. Just, it quite evidently doesn't adress it according to your specification! — Note that lists with a fixed number of elements are generally nicer constructed / deconstructed with list syntax instead of `:`, i.e. write `[x₁]` instead of `x₁:[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confusing as your question is, this is the answer:

```
g2 (x1:x2:xs) (y:ys) = x1:x2:y:(g2 xs ys)
g2 (x1:[]) (y:ys) = x1:y:[]
g2 [] [] = []
-- Added missing patterns, don't know what the function is supposed to do here
g2 [] (y:ys) = []
g2 (x1:xs) [] = []
```

Comment: Sorry, my english is not very good, sometimes my questions become to cryptic :) How exactly does the two patterns g2 [] (y:ys) = []
g2 (x1:xs) [] = [] solve the problem?

Comment: I just added them to cover all cases possible, so you don't get a runtime error that your function isn't defined for such arguments. It will just return `[]` then

Comment: Okey i understand and is pattern matching useful if you want to create large functions? (question from a haskell beginner, sorry)

Comment: You generally want to keep functions small, this amount of pattern matching is kind of a lot and you can easily get lost and forget about a case

Comment: @MartinM If you enable warnings (with the `-Wall` flag) the compiler will warn about potentially non-exhaustive patterns, helping you to define a function in all cases.